# Is there a good algorithm to detect 2 matrix are similar

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have two matrix like below (A) and (B) ↓

I want to know ,

1) Is the number (7,6) in (B) is also in (A)

2) Is B is 66%up like A .....

And ,how can I do that with CSharp?

Thanks for your advices.....

```
    (A)
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000011111111100000010000000001000000000
    000000000001000000010000000001000000000
    000000000100000000010000000001000000000
    000000001000000000010000000001000000000
    000000010000000000010000000001111111110
    000000100000000000010000000001000000010
    000001000000000000010000000001000000010
    000010000000000000010000000001111111110
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000




    (B)
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000011111111100000000000000001000000000
    000000000001000000000000000001000000000
    000000000100000000000000000001000000000
    000000001000000000000000000001000000000
    000000010000000000000000000001111111110
    000000100000000000000000000001000000010
    000001000000000000000000000001000000010
    000010000000000000000000000001111111110
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: What does "Is B is 66%up like A" mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "66% like"? I understand that 100% like is identical, but how does that degrade? If I have a matrix that has ones where you have zeroes and zeroes where you have ones, how resembling are these?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english...  I mean , A has 7 , 1 , 6 and B only has 7 , 6 , so there is 2/3 ~ 0.66    ...and also if the 7 in (B) is not completely...the result will less than 0.66 ...

Comment: Are you talking about optical character recognition?

Comment: @William Mioch Oh Yes , I really don't know how to translate to english at first... Thank you~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCR (Optical Character Recognition) is a huge field - and not my field.

Neural networks are a potential solution depending on your situation. There is a C# solution on this Code Project page:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/neural_network_ocr.aspx

Otherwise, check out all these duplicate questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-ocr-library
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512271/any-free-ocr-library-for-c

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind words. And also if you could taught me some english.....:)